# Referencing breqn's dgroup with cleveref

Tags: cleveref, breqn

The code

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{dgroup}
  \label{eq:mygroup}
  \begin{dmath}
    a = b
  \end{dmath},
  \begin{dmath}
    c = b
  \end{dmath}.
\end{dgroup}
%
As one can see from \cref{eq:mygroup}
\begin{dmath}
  a = c
\end{dmath}.
\end{document}
```

produces the text

> As one can see from eq. (1)

However, I would like the text to use the plural as I am referencing multiple equations, i.e.

> As one can see from eqs. (1)

How do I obtain the desired result? Can I force `cleveref` to use the plural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know there are several equations in the group, so you can help `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{pluralequation}{#2eqs.~(#1)#3}
\Crefformat{pluralequation}{#2Eqs.~(#1)#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{dgroup}
  \label[pluralequation]{eq:mygroup}
  \begin{dmath}
    a = b
  \end{dmath},
  \begin{dmath}
    c = b
  \end{dmath}.
\end{dgroup}
As one can see from \cref{eq:mygroup}
\begin{dmath}
  a = c
\end{dmath}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When one uses the `capitalize` option you have to define `\crefformat{pluralequation}{#2Eqs.~(#1)#3}`. (I just read about this in section 7.1 of the `cleveref` manual.) It might also be a good idea to set `\Crefformat{pluralequation}{#2Equations~(#1)#3}` as `\Cref` is meant primarily for the beginning of sentences.